# After PHP Search from MySQL how to add as results more rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small search script.. It must match firstname and lastname. Now if they search it and it match then it Shows now "Found".. But each Data in the Database has:

Firstname
Lastname
Birthday
Reason

now on the search script I only use First and Lastname to find but if there is a match, I want to Show all this 4 row of the result.. Some help please:

```html
<?php
// gets value sent over search form
$query = $_GET['query']; 
$query1 = $_GET['query1'];

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
    // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;


    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
    // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guests WHERE name1 LIKE '".$query."' AND lastname LIKE '".$query1."' ") or die(mysql_error());


        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){

            echo "Found";
            // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
        }

    }
    else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
        echo "No results";
    }


}
else{ // if query length is less than minimum
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
?>
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Instead of `echo "Found";` use `print_r($results);`, that will show all the data.

Comment: Works great.. But it Show like:
Array ( [0] => name [name1] => name [1] => lastname [lastname] => Lastname [2] => 24.04.1960 [birthday] => 24.04.1960 [3] => 7 [id] => 7 [4] => Reason why: XXX [reason] => Reason why: XXX) 

Hot can I make to Show like:
Firstname:
Lastname:
Birthday:
Reason:

Thanks again!

Comment: As the php documentation states too, the `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated for a long time now. Use pdo or mysqli instead. You can find more info here https://secure.php.net/mysql_query

Answer (score 2):

Your code has to be rethought for very basic security reasons. NEVER trust ANY user input, anything the user provides your server has to be sanitized before being used in the code. This will save you a lot of headaches and will surely come in handy when someone tries to pass a bad query.

Now, besides that, you also need to upgrade your code to at least `MySQLi` since - as I mentioned in the comments - MySQL has been deprecated.

Now to your code:

```
<?php
$localhost = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'users';
$mysqli = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $database);


if( isset( $_GET['query'] ) || isset( $_GET['query1'] ) )
{
    $firstname = (!empty($_GET['query'])) ? htmlentities($_GET['query'], ENT_QUOTES) : '';
    $lastname = (!empty($_GET['query1'])) ? htmlentities($_GET['query1'], ENT_QUOTES) : '';
    $min_length = 5;
    if(strlen($firstname) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usernames WHERE name1 LIKE ? OR lastname LIKE ?";

        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare( $sql ))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $firstname, $lastname);
            $stmt->execute();
            // here is the fix
            // bind the results into variables
            $results = $stmt->bind_result($s_id, $s_firstname, $s_lastname);
            $i = 0;
            // loop through all the results that you receive back
            while($stmt->fetch())
            {
                // create a new variable for them
                $rows[$i] = array(
                    'id' => $s_id,
                    'firstname' => $s_firstname,
                    'lastname' => $s_lastname,
                );
                $i++;
            }
            $stmt->close();
        }

        if($rows > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following 
        ?>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?=$row['id']?></td>
                            <td><?=$row['firstname']?></td>
                            <td><?=$row['lastname']?></td>
                            <!-- ...etc... -->
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </table>
        <?php } else { // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "No results";
        }


    }
    else{ // if query length is less than minimum
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
}
else
{
    echo "variables not set!";
}
```

`$results` will be a 2d array with Column name and Value of that column. This is helpful because you can play and handle those records in whatever you way you see fit.

I hope this helps, for more on Prepared Statements and MySQLi look under these resources:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: That's a server error. What is your current Server Application? Are you running this on your `localhost`? What's the current PHP version you have installed?

Comment: Running on Shared Hosting. Current PHP version: 5.6.33

Comment: Instead of `define()` change them to simple `var`: `$localhost = 'localhost' ...` and then change the `mysqli($localhost, ...)` Let me know if that fixes that.

Comment: What do you want that I Change on mysqli($localhost, ...)? Thanks

Comment: `$mysqli = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $database);`

Comment: var(LOCALHOST, 'localhost');
var(USERNAME, 'XX);
var(PASSWORD, 'XX');
var(DATABASE, 'XX');
$mysqli = new mysqli($LOCALHOST, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD, $DATABASE);

still getting error 500.. My Code before was working but only was putting so ugly results :D

Comment: No no no... `$localhost = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'users';

$mysqli = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $database);`

Comment: Done but still:

HTTP 500 error
That’s odd… the website can’t display this page

Comment: @Jerome hold on a sec... I will try something real quick

Comment: Ok :) ... thanks a lot.. getting my head like creazy.. trying so Long already.. then I had finaly some working Version but the results was ugly :D

Comment: @Jerome I have updated my code to something that should work now... Sorry about that first fail... that should set you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks so much.. But still:

HTTP 500 error
That’s odd… the website can’t display this page
The site may be undergoing maintenance or could have a programming error.
Try this
Go back to the last page
Try contacting the website’s owner

:(

Answer (score 0):

Got it working like this:

```html
<?php
$localhost = 'localhost';
$username = '';
$password = '';
$dbname = '';


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$query = $_GET['query']; 
$query1 = $_GET['query1'];
$query2 = $_GET['query2'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM guests WHERE name1 LIKE '".$query."' AND lastname LIKE '".$query1."' AND birthday LIKE '".$query2."' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>Name: ".$row["name1"]." <br>Lastname: ".$row["lastname"]." <br>Birthday: ".$row["birthday"]." <br>Reason: ".$row["reason"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Thanks to all for helping!